# remove desimal digits from price

Tags: magento-1.9, price, products

I am using Magento 1.9.2 with luxury theme 1.2.X

My product page shows price of the product like `999.0000`  I want to remove the price after decimal points.

I want to show Price like this `999`.

Here is my code for Price

```
<?php $_price = $this->getProduct()->getprice(); ?>
    <?php if($_price) : ?>
        <span><strong>MRP: </strong></span><span style="color:red;"><?php echo $this->helper('catalog/output')->productAttribute($this->getProduct(), $_price, 'price') ?></span>
    <?php endif ?>
```

how to achieve it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$price = $this->getProduct()->getprice();
$store = Mage::app()->getStore(null);
$currency = $store->getCurrentCurrency();
$price = $currency->formatPrecision($price, 0, array(), true, false);
```

Comment: Ya! I have tried installing it but it giving me `Could not resolve host: magento-community` error

Comment: @parish check my edited answer

Comment: @parish let me know it work or not ?

Comment: I have to echo `$price` right?  It's giving me output like `₹0.00` this

Comment: after this `$currency = $store->getCurrentCurrency();` line I am getting correct output... Some problem after last line

Comment: @parish check now

Answer (score 0):

```
$formattedPrice = Mage::helper('core')->currency($finalPrice, true, false);

$formattedPrice = Mage::helper('core')->formatPrice($_finalPrice, false);
```

**To display price without currency symbol on frontend:**

```
Mage::getModel('directory/currency')->formatTxt($_finalPrice, array('display' => Zend_Currency::NO_SYMBOL));
```